# On the derivative of probability density functions

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions, lebesgue-measure, weak-derivatives

By definition, a random variable $X$ has density $f_X$, if

$$P(\mathbf{a}\leq X\leq \mathbf{b}, t)=\int _{\mathbf{a}}^{\mathbf{b}}f_{X}(\mathbf{x}, t)\,\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}$$

Now, for this integral to be well-defined is necessary to have at least $f_X(\mathbf{x}, t)\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^+)$.
But suppose I want to compute a derivative of $f_X$. It is all right if the derivative operator is applied after the integral, but can it be brought inside?
I'm afraid it can't be done. As an example, any truncated Weierstrass function is integrable, but it remains nowhere differentiable.
So how is one supposed to do it?

Comment: What could $t$ possible be, this it not standard.

Comment: $t$ has the meaning of time, usually

Comment: You need to supply more context. For the intergal to be defined, $f$ just needs to be $L^1$ in the first parameter.